# Possible to get OpenDNS to dereference Host on VPN?

Tags: vpn, opendns

I recently changed ISPs for my home internet.  I am now having some trouble getting back into the corporate network from home over the VPN.

I have figured out that OpenDNS is resolving the Hosts on the VPN incorrectly when I am using TCP/IP.

When I browse to one of the hosts on corporate network, i.e. \host1, from the file manager this succeeds.

However, when I ping the host, i.e. ping host1, the IP address is resolving to the OpenDNS name server instead of the actual Host IP address.

Does anyone know how to make this work?  On a hunch, I turned off type correction.  But, this did not help.

**Edit:** My OS is Windows 7.  I'm using the software VPN, Hamachi.  The new ISP is Comcast.

Answer (score 1):

In general terms you want to use a DNS server provided by the VPN connection before OpenDNS.  How you do that in practise will depend on what operating system you are running, the vpn technology, and how you have OpenDNS configured.

You may find it easier to just not use OpenDNS.  If you used a DNS provider which returned an error rather than a succesful response on a non-existent hostname then it might just start working.  Note the 'might' and may', it will depend on your setup and we can't help you without more details.

Comment: The background on this issue, is that I recently started using Comcast for home internet service.  Comcast hijacks the DNS and will return success on mispelled URLs.  I tried to use OpenDNS to solve this problem, but it turns out OpenDNS is doing the same thing.  I'm using Windows 7.  How do I get the VPN DNS to get the first shot at resolving the host name?